# A solution satisfying an integral inequality is bounded

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, differential-equations, integration, integral-transforms

Let $y$ be a positive function and $c>0$. If $y$ satisfies the following integral inequality
\begin{equation}
y(t)+\int_{0}^{t}y(s)ds\leq c_{1}\int_{0}^{t} y^{\frac{3}{2}}(s)ds+c_{2}
\end{equation}
How can I prove that $y$ is bounded.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, the question should be interpreted as follows:

> Let $y\colon[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be a measurable function satisfying the inequality
> \begin{equation}
> y(t)+\int_0^t y(s)\,ds\le c_1\int_0^t y^{3/2}(s)\,ds+c_2
> \end{equation}
> for some positive real $c_1$ and $c_2$ and all real $t\ge0$.
> Is then $y$ necessarily bounded?

The answer then is: of course, not. For an obvious  counterexample, let $y(t)=t^2$ for all real $t\ge0$, $c_1=4
$, $c_2=1$.